# RAR password cracker

Tags: passwords, encryption, rar, winrar

Does the [RAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR) file format use a serious encryption (such as [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard))?

Will it take unfeasibly long to brute force a password?

If not, what tools do you suggest that do so automatically?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/106951/how-do-i-recover-the-password-of-a-rar-file-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does the RAR file format use a serious
>   encryption (such as AES)?

The current version of the [RAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinRAR) file format is using AES encryption with 128-bit key length.

> Will it take unfeasibly long to brute
>   force a password?

That depends entirely on the strength of the password.

> What tools do you suggest that do so
>   automatically?

There are some shareware programs (e.g. [RAR Password Cracker](http://download.cnet.com/RAR-Password-Cracker/3000-2092_4-10127912.html), [RAR Password Recovery](http://download.cnet.com/RAR-Password-Recovery/3000-2092_4-10312614.html)) using 'brute force' and 'dictionary-based' attacks to crack the password, the process can be very time consuming (again, depending on the password strength).

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't know which mechanism exactly, RAR used pretty solid encryption. Brute force attacks on it have been known to last :), for all but the simplest of passwords.

*(There were some password extracting mechanisms for old versions of RAR, but I do mean oooold, ... DOS days or something from that time period).*