# winrar how to remove that password?

Tags: passwords, winrar, password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RAR Password recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/106951/rar-password-recovery)

Ok I "forgot" my WinRAR password.

So basically I was googling for a solution and found **Winrar password recovery** and **winrar cracker**.

Both of these tools tries to dictionary attack or brute force the file.

I was thinking isn't there a better solution (like a program which breaks the file apart in it's binary state, modifying the file and recreating a new file which doesn't have a password) Or something like that?

I mean I don't mind if it took 1 week to force it's way through but I'm sure it's gonna take more than 10 years because "my" password is tough man.

Comment: You are probably out of luck then, because that password is used to encrypt the file, and it uses 128-bit AES encryption to protect it. Brute force is probably the only way. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinRAR

Comment: The other question is about OSX but the accepted solution works on win and linux as well.