# How to decompress a password protected rar file without the password?

Tags: rar

I have a `rar` file which is **password** protected. I forgot the password. Is there any way that will extract this file without giving the actual password ?

Comment: *How to unrar a password procted rar file?* Type in the password.

Comment: We need a lot more information. Tell us everything you do remember about the password. Was it words? Numbers? Did it have punctuation? How long was it? Give us everything you got and there's at least a small chance we can help you.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/106951/how-do-i-recover-the-password-of-a-rar-file-on-mac-os-x?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

No, there is **no way** to extract the files **without** giving it a password.

There are ways, however, to get the password back.

You didn't specify your OS but if you're on Linux you could try [RarCrack](http://rarcrack.sourceforge.net/).

There are a lot of password crackers to be found on the internet.
You can take a look [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/tp/password-cracker-recovery.htm) for a few of them. This site show a link to [crark.net](http://www.crark.net/) for Rar-files.

Otherwise take a look at [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=crack+rar+password). It shows a lot of them on the first 2 pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this [jpassrecovery](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpassrecovery/?source=directory) which is password recovery tool on sourceforge.